# failed to make query faster in hive using reducer and mappers

Tags: performance, query-optimization, hiveql, parquet

so I've been working on transferring data from oracle into hive with parquet format.

The format looks like this:

```
create external table if not exists 
partitioned by(datee string)
stored as parquet
tblproperties ('hive.exec.compress.output'='true', 'parquet.compression'='SNAPPY')
```

My question is how to tune this query (eats about 4 hours) into 5 minutes query?

I already try this query (put before my query) of these combinations:

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
sethive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
```

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled=false;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

```
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled = true;
```

But the results is going nowhere.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: where is query? And also please provide more details: execution logs (how many mappers, reducers), EXPLAIN PLAN output

Comment: sholud I put all the query? the query is about 400 lines..

Comment: yes you should. and please also EXPLAIN output and few lines of execution log

Comment: but much better prepare minimal reproducible example. Without logs, explain plan and query this question can not be solved